# Publish project in existing branch in Git

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

My organization currently uses Git as source control. I have created an empty branch (say `Test`) under the `master` branch in the current work repository. I have one POC project that I want to push into that empty branch (`Test`). My POC project sits under a different folder path locally than the repository folder path.

I am pretty new to GIT as source control and really not able to figure out how I can push the project into the new branch. Can someone help me?

Note: I am using the GitHub Windows client. An answer that uses the UI would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would involve Subtree merging, basically you would create a repo for your POC project and add it as a remote to your main project then update your empty branch with the content from the POC remote (after fetching), you will find more detailed info here : [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#Other-Types-of-Merges) - Look under subtree merging subsection. (Please check EDIT2)
I think you can achieve the same effect using submodules.

I hope this will help.

EDIT: Not sure if this is possible with the UI alone.

EDIT2: Maybe it shouldn't involve subtree merging, since you POC project isn't a subdir of your main project. But I think you can do what you would like to do if you create a repo for your POC and use that repos as a remote for the main project. Let's say you created a repo for the POC project, you would then proceed as follows. (In your main repo)

(1) Add local repo as remote :
`git remote add <poc_remote> <poc_path>`

(2) Fetch data : `git fetch <poc_remote>`

(3) Create a branch solely used to track the other repo, copy the data and checkout `git checkout -b <branch> <poc_remote>/master`

(4) Or if you already have a branch `test` :

```
$git checkout test
$git branch -u <poc_remote>/master   //sets your local branch to track the remote master branch.
$git pull
```